# Alp to change what is echoed

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16

```
.model tiny
.486
.data
  max1 db 10
  act1 db ?
  inp1 db 32 dup(0)
.code
.startup
  lea dx, max1
  mov ah, 0ah
  int 21h
.exit
end
```

I want * to be echoed instead of the characters that I type. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I wonder where you people get that second byte of buffer for `ah=0Ah` as `?`. It's *"number of chars from last input which may be recalled"*, so you should set it to 0 (unless you prepared some data into the buffer to be recalled).

Secondly you will have to not use this `0Ah` service, but [`ah=8` stdin _no_echo service](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah08) to read chars one by one, and output asterisk on your own (for example by `ah=2` service). = so you have to do your own buffer/loop logic, validating maximum length, etc...